# What is the Difference Between Float and Double Data Types?

Tags: data-types, floating-point

Apart from the memory size of both data types, I want to know any other differences and also want to know when we use float and when we use double?

Answer (score 1):

You can look up the concrete difference between `float` and `double` variables easily by searching for those terms; this group is not for answering simple definition queries, and anyway the details vary depending on your programming language and implementation.

But you can reason from fundamental principles about what the answer *must be like*. Increased memory size for a data type is a *cost*. A cost **must** be offset by some benefit, otherwise people wouldn't bother having the costly type in the first place. The principal assets that computing systems deal in are *time* and *space*. Therefore, increased space requirements probably allow us to perform some computation in less *time*.

Why would this be? Doesn't `double` simply support *the same* computation with higher precision? It is only the same computation as long as you don't actually are about that higher precision. If you *do* care about a certain level of precision, then `double` allows you to do things in one step that you would otherwise have to emulate with multiple `float` operations.

And there you have your answer: `double` allows you to perform calculations *in a particular range* or *at a particular precision* that is greater than the range, or the precision, you could achieve with `float` values. This means that it very much depends on the details of your task description whether or not it is worthwhile to use the smaller or the larger numeric type. (And that is exactly the answer you'd get if you simply asked that question e.g. in a  C programming forum.)

Comment: `double` is usually recommended for individual variables (as opposed to large arrays) because your CPU can do double math about as quickly as it can do float math, so there's not much downside.